# RDBMS : Move frequently updated columns into a separate table

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I have a table Users (simplified) :

```
UserId (int, PK) | Username | PasswordHash | LastVisitTimestamp
```

Every time user visits a web site, LastVisitTimestamp column is updated.

Is it a good idea to move that column into a separate table, so that timestamp updates do not lock entire row (actual row is bigger than presented here).

I did that because I was frequently getting "row modified" exception when updating user information (result of update with optimistic concurrency).

Or is there a better (preferred) way to handle this?

Comment: "row modified" -- souhds like you have multiple SQL statements that need to be combined in a "transaction".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is totally legit way of solving the problem.

Another ideas are storing such data in memory-based storage, accumulate and dump to database once per few seconds in batches...